# Dataset type problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql, dataset, types

I've got a few datatables in an Microsoft SQL database. I get those with an dataadapter and put them into a dataset. After this I want to change a few of the values, like some I want to change to: "Na/Na". Now the problem in this is, that the normal Type of this column is INT. So it gives me an error.

Is there a way in which I can make sure all the columns get STRING as their type? Or can I make sure the schema of the datatables doesn't get used, I know I could make all the columns myself in C# and then get the values by an query, but this would be WAY to much work.

Comment: Do you need this value to be saved to the DB, or just need it for display?

Comment: Do you really think you should actually do it ? This is possible and I can write good solution but I won't. I really advice you to find an alternate to what you want to do.

Comment: I got some values I want to "spec" this means I want to see if the values are within a certain values. Then I'll give the cell an true or an false. This is just for display, but afterwards I'll make new datatables in the database with only string types. And put the new "specced" table back into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try cloning the `DataTable` and altering the data types of each column, as suggested in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1128563.aspx) post. (Scroll about half way down for the answer).

The other alternative is to change (or create a) stored procedure that gets your data and make that pass back the correct "Na/Na" type values you want.

Comment: The first solution sounds good, I think I'm going for that one. I know the stuff I'm doing is not 100% as it should be. But I get all kinds of stupid values from a company and need to make something decent out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a way but it isn't perfect.
The way is to cast fields to varchar in query or stored procedure. It'll be better (if possible) that you make your "Na/Na" changes on MS SQL Server side in stored procedure.

Comment: This sounds ok, I want the dataadapter to put all the values into the dataset as datatype.String.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just one column causing you the problem? You coudl always in the databse convert it to nvarchar or something before sending it to the C#. Then the column type would be a string. Alternatively you could almost certainyl write some code that would look at the types of a column and if it finds integer ones add a new column to the DataTable and copy the data across to it. That is coming perilously close to your suggestion of making columns for all of them yourself though.

Lastly if your integers are actually limited to a certain range (ie they are always positive) then you could use a magic value (like -1) to represent N/A and then in whatever code you use to process this make sure you recognise the magic value before doing stuff with it.

I don't think (though I would be delighted to be corrected) that you can just change what type a column is and have all the current values get converted automatically.

Comment: I already thought about your solution, but the problem is there are some -1 values in those tables, which could also be true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a "typed dataset", and do you only need to display "Na/Na" on some occasions?

Then you can easily add a property to the partial class of your datatable which is a string and just returns what you need to display:

```
public partial class DataSet1 {
    partial class DataTable1DataTable
    {
        public string MyStringColumn {
            get {
                return IntColumn <= 0 ? "Na/Na" : IntColumn.ToString();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if you didn't read my previous comment. But I also need to store it later on. Found other solution posted above which looks good, not the most "neat" way to do it, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the DataType of a column after the datatable has been filled with data. 
So you need to define the datatables first by adding the columns in C#.
However you can still use the `adapter.Fill` command, but using the second parameter, to specify the name of the DataTable you want to fill in the Dataset.

```
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
DataTable DT = new DataTable("Table1");
DT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("column1", typeof(string)));
DS.Tables.Add(DT);

adapter.Fill(ds , "Table1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Look at the other solution I used, it works well, isn't slow for my tables and fixes the problem.